# Redirect Loop happen when the session is not set

Tags: php, redirect

"Session.php"

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
        {                                       
           header('Location: ./index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page per il login
           exit;
        }
session_start();// Start new session or resume existing session
    //echo 'session_id: '.session_id();
    
    require "connessione.php";
    $connessione = connessionedb("db");
    
         
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $username = $connessione->real_escape_string($username);
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM utenti where idUtente= '$username' ";
    $risultato = mysqli_query($connessione, $query);
    
    $num_record = mysqli_num_rows ($risultato);
    if ($num_record!=1)
    {
         header('Location: ./index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page per il login
         $con->close();
         exit; 
    }
```

I want it to send me back to the home when there isn't a session, but it will make a redirect loop.

Comment: Do you have this check in `index.php`? That page shouldn't redirect.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get what you said, could you be more specific? I'm pretty much a novice

Comment: You'll get a redirect loop if `index.php` redirects to `index.php`. So the above session check shouldn't be in `index.php`, it should just be in all the other scripts.

Comment: ok, to be more clear, i put a require "session.php" into index.php to create a session and to send back you to index.php if you try to access an unauthorized page when you don't have a session

Comment: But you're already on `index.php`, you can't send back to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Use different session check at the index file like

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){                                       
   
   header('Location: ./dashboard.php'); // Redirecting To Dasboard Page Already logged in
   exit;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this check when you're already on `index.php`.

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/index.php' && !isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
{                                       
   header('Location: ./index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page per il login
   exit;
}
```

Comment: It still redirect me to index.php from index.php. I'll edit the post and add some extra code snippets

Comment: `session_start()` has to be *before* you do `isset($_SESSION['username'])`

Comment: it is but i forgot to add it to the snippet. Btw I solved the problem by creating a check.php for the index only, but if you help me find a better solution it would awesome

Answer (score 0):

Your $_SESSION variable is not created until session_start(); is called.  Since you have session_start() after you are evaluating $_SESSION['username'], it will always come back as not set because $_SESSION itself is not set yet.

Also, as Barmar pointed out, if you are requiring session.php in your index.php file, and you havent started a session yet, then it will always cause a loop.  So since you are already inside index.php, just exit out.  Dont redirect.

Here is the code modification:

```
session_start();// Start new session or resume existing session
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
    {                                       
       exit;
    }
//echo 'session_id: '.session_id();

require "connessione.php";
$connessione = connessionedb("db");

     
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$username = $connessione->real_escape_string($username);

$query = "SELECT * FROM utenti where idUtente= '$username' ";
$risultato = mysqli_query($connessione, $query);

$num_record = mysqli_num_rows ($risultato);
if ($num_record!=1)
{
     header('Location: ./index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page per il login
     $con->close();
     exit; 
}
```